# Sort dictionary based on value and extract the corresponding keys

Tags: ios, swift

I have a dictionary data structure in Swift with key,value pair, I want to sort the dictionary in descending order based on the value and then get the top 3 keys corresponding to top 3 values.

example:

before sort:

```
Dictionary<'A', 8>
Dictionary<'B', 23>
Dictionary<'C', 56>
Dictionary<'D', 3>
Dictionary<'E', 9>
Dictionary<'F', 20>
```

After sort:

```
 Dictionary<'C', 56>
 Dictionary<'B', 23>
 Dictionary<'F', 20>
 Dictionary<'E', 9>
 Dictionary<'A', 8>
 Dictionary<'D', 3>
```

so I need C, B and A

Comment: Do you mean you want C, B, and *F*?

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant C, B and F, thanks for pointing this out... and thanks everyone for the answers !

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 3):

To get the first three keys associated with the dictionary's sorted values, (1) sort the array by its values, (2) get the keys in order from that sorted array, then (3) pull out the first 3 keys from that array:

```
let dict = ["A":8, "B":23, "C":56, "D":3, "E":9, "F":20]

// Sort the dictionary by its values
let sortedArray = sorted(dict, {$0.1 > $1.1})

// Get an array of the keys from the sorted array
let keys = sortedArray.map {return $0.0 }

// Get the first three keys
let firstThreeKeys = keys[0..<3]
println(firstThreeKeys)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 2 you can do for example this:

```
let dict = ["A":8, "B":23, "C":56, "D":3, "E":9, "F":20]

let sa = dict.sort({$0.1 > $1.1}).prefix(3).map { $0.0 } // ["C", "B", "F"]
```

Comment: Very cool! But this returns the values not the keys, i.e. [56, 23, 20]

Answer (score 0):

```
for (key,value) in (Array(arr).sorted {$0.1 < $1.1}) {
    println("\(key):\(value)")
}
```

Comment: That's only half the problem. OP wants the first three keys, in order.